# Removing accents from certain characters

Tags: c#, performance, strings, .net, unicode

I have a method that I am using to remove accents from certain characters. The problem is the massive slew of characters I am expected to work with. I have to, basically, remove accents from **all** Latin characters that fit within the 26 English Latin characters. (`A` through `Z`.) Performance is a **very** large requirement. It has to be lightning fast, as I have to run this on **every** character within a string, and process many *large* strings at a time.

Currently, I use a gigantic `switch` statement to detect what character it is, and return the appropriate `A` through `Z` "naked" character, while preserving case.

As of now, my `switch` looks something like the following:

```
switch (input)
{
    case 'À': // 0192
    case 'Á': // 0193
    case 'Â': // 0194
    case 'Ã': // 0195
    case 'Ä': // 0196
    case 'Å': // 0197
    case 'Ā': // 0256
    case 'Ă': // 0258
    case 'Ą': // 0260
        return 'A';
    case 'Ç': // 0199
    case 'Ć': // 0262
    case 'Ĉ': // 0264
    case 'Ċ': // 0266
    case 'Č': // 0268
        return 'C';
    case 'Ď': // 0270
    case 'Đ': // 0272
        return 'D';
    // Other upper case characters
    case 'à': // 0224
    case 'á': // 0225
    case 'â': // 0226
    case 'ã': // 0227
    case 'ä': // 0228
    case 'å': // 0229
    case 'ā': // 0257
    case 'ă': // 0259
    case 'ą': // 0261
        return 'a';
    case 'ç': // 0231
    case 'ć': // 0263
    case 'ĉ': // 0265
    case 'ċ': // 0267
    case 'č': // 0269
        return 'c';
    case 'ď': // 0271
    case 'đ': // 0273
        return 'D';
    // Other lower case characters
    default:
        return input;
}
```

As you can probably imagine, this method is **over 200 lines**, and this is the only thing it does.

```
private char RemoveAccent(char input)
{
    switch (input)
    {
        // You saw all the case statements
    }
}
```

Literally, that is it. My questions come down to the following, and this is more of a question of performance/better ways of handling the situation.

I know I can take a `Regex` and do the same thing very easily. It's what I used in the beginning as a shortcut. The problem, is that the regex is **phenomenally slow**. Essentially, what I was doing is looping over the 26 alphas, and then using the regex `"[ALPHACHARACTER]"`, and replacing it with `ALPHACHARACTER`.

This method, however, was horrendous in performance. Over a set of input `x`, with data logic `y`, it was a whopping 1500ms.

Now, when I exclude this method from the logic, it performed at about 110ms. This is with the same input `x` and logic `y`, mind you. The only difference is that this method had a body of `return input;`.

So, I went to the `switch` method, which is **very high** in performance, and **very low** in maintainability. (The `Calculate Code Metrics` in Visual Studio puts it at a 41 for this method.) This one performed at 120ms with the exact same remaining logic 'y' and input 'x' as the `Regex` option. This allows me to exclude all other logic as being the issue.

The only other option I can think of, is to use an `if` statement on character ranges to at least make it more maintainable. The question on it is performance.

```
if ((input >= 'À' && input <= 'Å') || (input >= 'Ā' && input <= 'Ą' && input % 2 == 0))
    return 'A';
else if ((input == 'Ç') || (input >= 'Ć' && input <= 'Č' && input % 2 == 0))
    return 'C';
else if (input >= 'Ď' && input <= 'Đ' && input % 2 == 0)
    return 'D';
// Other upper case characters
else if ((input >= 'à' && input <= 'å') || (input >= 'ā' && input <= 'ą' && input % 2 == 1))
    return 'A';
else if ((input == 'ç') || (input >= 'ć' && input <= 'č' && input % 2 == 1))
    return 'C';
else if (input >= 'ď' && input <= 'đ' && input % 2 == 1)
    return 'D';
// Other lower case characters

return input;
```

Also, this is not all of the inputs. The 200 lines I mentioned earlier doesn't even cover a quarter of the characters I have to support. The thing is, I find the `switch` more readable, personally.

My questions are:

1. Is there a significantly more readable way, to write this, without significantly losing performance?
2. Is my `switch` statement the way to go if I favour performance over maintainability?
3. Should I stick with it regardless of what metrics Visual Studio might mention if it's more readable/understandable to me, and already has acceptable performance?
4. Is there something already in .NET to do what I am that might perform faster?

The only reason I ask these things, is that I feel like I'm *doing something wrong*, like I'm missing something in the way I approach this.

Personally, I think that since I find it readable, and it's already fast enough, there's no point to change it. The only problem is that I still have a lot of options to add to it, so it will only grow in size. The management of it could get a bit out of hand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This appears to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net). The link suggests using .NET's [`String.Normalize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.normalize(v=vs.110).aspx). If it's too slow, you could simply create an associative array (e.g., a `Dictionary` that maps `char`->`char`) for constant-time lookup. This is going to be large, too, but I would think it's probably easier to maintain.

Comment: Interesting, that seems to be working quite well, and is just as quick as my switch. (Maybe even faster.) I think it's safe to say that this resolves my issue, and I'm not sure why I decided to do it the hard way. (I'm not sure how I missed that SO question. I guess I just assumed no one else has this issue.)